# Should my trust be the beneficiary of my annuities?

Tags: united-states, taxes, inheritance, trusts, estate-planning

My home and additional acreage are in a revocable trust.  I also have IRA annuities and non-qualified annuities.  At this time the beneficiaries are my three adult children.  At my death, I would like everything distributed evenly between them.  They have stated that they would not want the IRAs transferred even though there would be great taxation.  My son wants my home and one daughter wants the acreage.  Should I make the trust beneficiary on the annuities so that everything can be distributed equally between the three from the trust?

Answer (score 4):

Generally you'd want to discuss this with an estate *attorney*, while also consulting with a tax specialist (EA/CPA licensed in your state) since attorneys often times don't know taxes all that well unless they're explicitly practicing tax law.

Specifically to your points:

- You *can* technically have any legal entity you want as a beneficiary, including trusts.
- It would probably be better to put individuals as IRA beneficiaries.
- You do want to check whether annuities will even be included in your estate, since most annuities are for *your* lifetime and end with you.
- You need to talk to a tax adviser about trust taxation and how it can affect the amounts distributed to the beneficiaries.
- You also need to have a trustworthy reliable *trustee* to execute your wishes, which may also be expensive depending on who the trustee is and how much they charge for the service. However, avoiding probate may still be saving you money even with the trustee expenses.

Answer (score 0):

Making individuals the direct beneficiaries avoids having the money go through probate, making it available to them much more rapidly for use in cleaning up the things which *do* need to use probate for. I'd say designate beneficiaries wherever you can.